# Constructing objects in Java

Tags: java, object

I'm currently reading the book "Big Java Early Objects".

In the section "construction objects in Java" They gave this example below.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

/**
   This example demonstrates constructors.
*/
public class ConstructorDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Constructs and prints a rectangle
      System.out.println(new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30));

      // Constructs a rectangle and saves it in a variable
      Rectangle box = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30);
      System.out.print("box: ");
      System.out.println(box);

      // The constructor with no arguments
      box = new Rectangle();
      System.out.print("box: ");
      System.out.println(box);
   }
}
```

I think this code should print out a Rectangle. But nothing happens, it only prints out this in the Console:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=5,y=10,width=20,height=30]
box: java.awt.Rectangle[x=5,y=10,width=20,height=30]
box: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]
```

Is something wrong with my Eclipse? How can I make this work?

Comment: Why would it print out a rectangle? What do you mean by _print out a rectangle_?

Comment: It won't draw a rectangle.

Comment: It is calling `Rectangle#toString` method, and that String is being printed in the console.

Comment: It should draw a rectangle on the screen, and it should also color it to your liking :)

Comment: I would re-read that section of the book to understand what the code is _intended_ to demonstrate.  That code will most definitely NOT "draw" anything on the screen.

Comment: What a strange name for a book. Is it some well-known one?

Comment: @PlzDadStaph you don't know the definition of class `Rectangle` and while instantiating it's object you are presuming that upon calling its constructor it should do bla bla for you which is not entertained while instructing computers. Expect it to do particular thing only when you are sure it knows(or has been made known) to do that particular thing. I hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code for `Rectangle.toString()`, which is called automatically by `System.out.println`, you will see that it prints out the parameters that make up the `Rectangle` object. However, it will not draw it:

```
return getClass().getName() + "[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + ",width=" + width + ",height=" + height + "]";
```

You're not explicitly calling `toString()`, but impliclty you are:

See:

```
System.out.println(foo); // foo is a non primitive variable
```

[`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a class, with a `static` field [`out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out), of type [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). So you're calling the [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) method of a `PrintStream`.

It is implemented like this:

```
   public void println(Object x) {
       String s = String.valueOf(x);
       synchronized (this) {
           print(s);
           newLine();
       }
   }
```

As we see, it's calling the [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method. This is implemented as follows:

```
   public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
       return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
   }
```

And here you see, that [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is called.

Your code is operating normally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your Eclipse and the output is in fact correct. If you are expecting to see an actual drawing of a Rectangle then you need to re-look at Rectangle class. Calling System.out.print on a Rectangle Object calls the .toString method. This in turn is a representation of the coordinates and dimensions of the Rectangle you created.